# Proof of this series converging to zero does not convince me

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I have a function $F$ that is bounded and such that $F(x) \to 0$ whenever $x\to 0$. Then, I have the following series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k}
$$
for $\delta > 0$. I want to show that this series converges to $0$ as $\delta\to 0$.

#### Proof from the book which I don't understand

Given $\epsilon > 0$ we choose $N$ so large that
$$
\sum_{k \geq N} \frac{1}{2^k} < \epsilon.
$$
Then, by making $\delta$ sufficiently small, we have (since $F(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$)
$$
F(2^k \delta) < \frac{\epsilon}{N}
$$
whenever $k=0, 1, \ldots, N-1$. Since $F$ is bounded then the result follows.

#### What I don't understand

I am very lost by this proof. What is it doing in the first step? How does it know I can find such an $N$? And how does it know that by choosing $\delta$ sufficiently small, I can bound $F(2^k \delta)$?

Comment: The series $\;\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{2^n}\;$ converges (to $2$. It is a geometric series), and this means the series' tail can be made as small as we want provided we begin the sum from some natural number...this is just Cauchy's condiction to convergence of sequences.

Comment: @DonAntonio I suppose one could also use the Ratio Test to see that $\frac{2^{-(k+1)}}{2^{-k}} = \frac{1}{2} <1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- In the first step, they take advantage of the fact that $F$ is bounded and $\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}\frac1{2^k}$ is convergent to prove that some tail of the series is sufficiently small, independently from $\delta.$ More precisely, given $\epsilon>0,$ for $N$ large enough (and this "large enough" is easy to calculate),
  $$\sum_{k\ge N}\frac1{2^k}=\frac1{2^{N-1}}<\epsilon$$
  hence if $|F|$ is bounded by some positive $M$ then $\left|\sum_{k\ge N}\frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k}\right|\le\sum_{k\ge N}\frac{|F(2^{k+1}\delta)|}{2^k}\le M\epsilon$ for every $\delta.$
- Now that $N$ is fixed, in the second step, there only remains to bound a *finite* number of terms of the series. For each $k<N,$ they prove that for *every* $\delta$ small enough, each of the $N$ first terms of the series will also be small. More precisely, given $\epsilon>0$ again, since $\lim_{x\to0}F(x)=0,$ there exists some $\alpha>0$ such that
  $$|x|<\alpha\Rightarrow|F(x)|<\frac\epsilon N,$$
  so that for *every* real number $\delta,$
  $$|\delta|<\frac\alpha{
  2^{N-1}}\implies\forall k\le N-1\quad|F(2^k\delta)|<\frac{\epsilon}N$$
  hence
  $$|2\delta|<\frac\alpha{
  2^{N-1}}\implies\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{|F(2^{k+1}\delta)|}{2^k}\le \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|F(2^{k+1}\delta)|<\epsilon.$$

Putting the two steps together, since
$$\left|\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k}\right|\le\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{|F(2^{k+1}\delta)|}{2^k}+\left|\sum_{k\ge N}\frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k}\right|,$$
they found that
$$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists\beta>0\quad\left(|\delta|<\beta\implies\left|\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k}\right|<\left(1+M\right)\epsilon\right).$$
For every $\varepsilon>0,$ applying this to $\epsilon=\frac\varepsilon{1+M}$ proves the claim, i.e.
$$\forall\varepsilon>0\quad\exists\beta>0\quad\left(|\delta|<\beta\implies\left|\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k}\right|<\varepsilon\right).$$

Comment: Thanks! I have a question. How do you know that this is true?
$$
\sum_{k \geq N} \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{2^{N-1}}
$$
I tried
$$
2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{2^k} + \sum_{k\geq N} \frac{1}{2^k}
$$
Giving 
$$
\sum_{k\geq N} \frac{1}{2^k} = 2 - \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{2^k}
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: $\sum_{k\ge N}\frac1{2^k}=\frac1{2^N}\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{2^n}.$

Comment: Okay thank you. I am still quite lost. Proving convergence would mean showing
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0, \, \exists \beta > 0\,:\, \left(|2^{k+1}\delta| < \beta \quad \implies \left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k}\right| < \epsilon\right)
$$

Comment: So then a standard proof would start with letting $\epsilon > 0$. Then, I want to find a $\beta$ such that the statement above is true

Comment: I don't understand how the steps link together. I understand that if we call 
$$
a_k = \frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k}
$$
then one can define
$$
b_k = \frac{M}{2^k}
$$
with $M > 0$ since $F$ is bounded. Then $0 \leq a_k \leq b_k$ and so by the comparison test if $\sum_k b_k$ converges, so does $\sum_k a_k$. However the $b_k$ series definitely converges since it's just a constant times
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = 2
$$
hence converges to $2M$, and so $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ converges too.

Answer (score 2):

> What is it doing in the first step? How does it know I can find such an $N$?

Because $\sum_{k\geq N}\frac1{2^k} = \frac1{2^N}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}=2^{-N}2=2^{1-N}$ and we just choose $N\geq1-\log_2(\varepsilon)$.

> And how does it know that by choosing $\delta$ sufficiently small, I can bound $F(2^k\delta)$?

The precise definition of $F(x)\to0$ as $x\to 0$ is:
$$\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\mu\forall x\colon |x|<\mu\Rightarrow |F(x)|<\varepsilon$$

(The usual definition uses $\delta$ instead of $\mu$, but we already have a different $\delta$ so I use $\mu$ to avoid confusion).

This means that if I choose some $\varepsilon$, for example $\varepsilon=\frac{\epsilon}{N}$, then I get a $\mu$ such that $F(x)<\varepsilon$ for all $x$ with $|x|<\mu$. Now if we take $\delta = \frac{\mu}{2^{N}}$, then all numbers $\delta 2^k$ for $k=1,2,\dots,N-1$ have $\delta 2^k<\mu$, so we have $F(\delta 2^k)<\varepsilon=\frac\epsilon N$.

Comment: In order to prove that $\lim_{\delta\to0}G(\delta)=0,$ it is not sufficient to prove that $\forall\varepsilon>0\quad\exists\delta(\varepsilon)>0\quad|G(\delta(\varepsilon))|\le\varepsilon.$

Comment: Nor did I say something like that

Comment: You did: you said "Now if we take $\delta=\dots$ we have $F(\delta2^k)<\varepsilon$" instead of something like "for *every* $\delta>0$ such that $|\delta|<\dots,$ we have $\dots$".

Comment: Yes, because this is the step OP did not understand. An extra step needed to show the full statement is to note that for all $\delta'\leq\delta$ the statement also holds. But OP did not ask for explanation of that step.

Answer (score 1):

the idea is to split the series into two separate sums. That means:

$\big\vert \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k} \big\vert \leq \big\vert \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k} \big\vert + \big\vert \sum_{k\geq N} \frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k} \big\vert.$

Now, both sums on the right hand side tend to zero, under different assumptions. The first one, by using the continuity of $F$ in $0$, combined with $F(0)=0$ and the second one, using the boundedness of $F$. In fact you can proceed the inequality as follows.

For the first term:
$\big\vert \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k} \big\vert \leq N \max_{k=0,...,N-1} \vert F(2^{k+1} \delta) \vert. \tag{1}$

And the second term:
$\big\vert \sum_{k\geq N} \frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k} \big\vert \leq M \sum_{k\geq N} \frac{1}{2^k}. \tag{2}$

Note, such an $M>0$ exists, since $F$ is bounded.
Now you are ready to prove the claim. You can pick an arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$. Then, since the second sum (2) tends to zero, you find some $N(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\sum_{k\geq N(\varepsilon)} \frac{1}{2^k} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

And, you can also find an $\delta(\varepsilon) >0$ small enough, s.t.
$\vert F(2^{k+1} \delta) \vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2 \cdot N(\varepsilon)}, \quad \forall \delta \leq \delta(\varepsilon)$, for all $k=0,...,N(\varepsilon)-1$. Which gives you

$N(\varepsilon) \max_{k=0,...,N(\varepsilon)-1} \vert F(2^{k+1} \delta) \vert \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \quad \forall \delta \leq \delta(\varepsilon).$

Put everything together, and you get
$\big\vert \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{F(2^{k+1}\delta)}{2^k} \big\vert \leq \varepsilon, \; \forall \delta \leq \delta(\varepsilon).$

This proves the claim, as $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary.

Comment: In order to prove that $\lim_{\delta\to0}G(\delta)=0,$ it is not sufficient to prove that $\forall\varepsilon>0\quad\exists\delta(\varepsilon)>0\quad|G(\delta(\varepsilon))|\le\varepsilon.$

Comment: Sure, for all $\delta \leq \delta(\varepsilon)$ was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k = S \in \mathbb{R}$ be a convergent series. Now define a "tail sum" sequence: $t_n = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}a_k$ 
Notice that this sequence is well defined because the series converges. Now we will prove that: $t_n \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$ 
Notice that $t_{n+1}=S-\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k$ whoever we know that by definition $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} S$ so using arithmetic of limits we get $t_{n+1} \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} S-S=0$ and thus also $t_n \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$ (because shifting a sequence does not impact the convergence or the limit itself). 
 Now substitute $a_k = 2^{-k}$ and use the definition of a limit of sequence on $t_n$ to get your desired $N$ for each $\epsilon$. 
Regarding your second doubt about $\delta$ consider the following: 
Let $0 < \epsilon, N$ be two numbers, we know that by the definition of the limit on the number $\epsilon/N$ there is some $0 < d$ such that $x \in (-d,d) \implies -\epsilon/N < F(x) < \epsilon/N$. Now the question is how to choose $0 < \delta$ such that $2^k\delta \in (-d,d)$ for $k=0,...,N-1$. Now note: 
$-d < 2^k\delta < d \Leftrightarrow -d/2^k < \delta < d/2^k$ so pick some $0<\delta$ such that: $-d/2^{N-1} < \delta < d/2^{N-1}$ and then because $(-d/2^{N-1},d/2^{N-1}) \subset (-d/2^k,d/2^k)$ for $k = 0,...,N-1$ that $\delta$ satisfies our requirement.